# GSAP cannot import modules with vue Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, gsap

I am working on a menu animation where I would like to add easings to my Tweens. With my current setup I have Tweenlite initialised and got some extra's that come with TweenLite (Power0-4 easings etc.).
However I cannot import any easing with nuxt.js and webpack.

My current setup looks like this:

**AppMenu.vue**

```
import TimelineLite from 'gsap/TimelineLite'
//import { Bounce, } from 'gsap/EasePack'
//import Test from 'gsap/umd/EasePack'
//import { Bounce, } from 'gsap/all'
//import { Bounce, } from 'gsap/index'

...

tl.add(
        TweenLite.fromTo(
          this.$refs.cta.$el,
          0.6,
          { opacity: 0, y: 500, },
          { y: 0, opacity: 1, ease: Bounce.EaseIn, }
        )
      )
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
transpile: [
      'gsap',
      'gsap/EasePack',
      'gsap/all',
    ],
```

Every Easing import results in stuff that doesn't work... Can someone help? :)

Comment: Double check [npm page for gsap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gsap#npm). Example import looks like this `import {TweenMax, Power2, TimelineLite} from "gsap/TweenMax";` or after 2.0 it's like this `import {TweenMax, CSSPlugin, ScrollToPlugin, Draggable, Elastic} from "gsap/all";`

Comment: import { TimelineLite, Bounce, Elastic, Circ, } from 'gsap/TweenMax'; In this import I can now only use the Elastic ease. Bounce and Circ return empty objects.